# Handle closing dialog window opened by current window

Tags: python, qt, pyside

i am total newbie in qt api.

I have MainWindow class:

```
class MainWindow(QDialog):

    # List of all connections
    data = []

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # ...
        # setting up layout 
        # ...
        self.newButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedNewButton)
        self.getData()
        self.addDataToList()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            self.addWindowObj.close()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        finally:
            event.accept()

    def getData(self):
        pass

    def addDataToList(self):
        pass

    @Slot()
    def clickedNewButton(self):
        self.addWindowObj = AddWindow()
        self.addWindowObj.initUi()
        self.addWindowObj.finished.connect(self.onAddFinish)
```

AddWindow is a class which extends QDialog.

I handled closing AddWindow when I am closing MainWindow (closeEvent).

But I need to handle closing AddWindow as well. 
I know I can do it from AddWindow class - but I what I exactly need is call *addDataToList* method on MainWindow instance.

I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: If AddWindow is a dialog, you can handle its `QDialog::accepted()` signal in the MainWindow and call `addDataToList()` function in the slot.

Comment: Does not work: 

    http://pastebin.com/yUWsaZYR

addWindow is a window which happens to extends QDialog :)

Comment: What does not work? How do you close the AddWindow? You have to close it with calling `QDialog::accept()` or `QDialog::done()` with `QDialog::Accepted` argument.

Comment: FYI, `closeEvent` on `MainWindow` is not needed. Just give the main window instance (`self`) as a parent to your dialog. That'll handle closing of the dialog when the main window is closed.